# Dynamicity inside a stationary water drop

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, chaos-theory

I was doing some experiments with water drops on lampblack when I saw this.

[image]

You can see the full video [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZfL4.jpg)
Inside a water drop which is perfectly still from the outside, you can see some moving things, which I suppose are some lampblack flakes from the surface. I am not bothered about how those flakes got in there, but I am interested in their motion.

**Why are they even moving?**
Is it some kind of Brownian motion?

I am amazed by the dynamicity inside such a seemingly inactive water droplet.

If I had not seen this, I would have considered the water drop as a simple sphere for the rest of my life.
This observation, at least for me, raises an important question.

Is anything in the world really NOT dynamic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the similar movement of inhomogeneities on soap bubbles, I'd say the flakes' movement is caused by air currents around the drop and perhaps thermal convection.

[image]
<sub>Source: https://youtu.be/LM3p3X92mWI</sub>

Comment: +1 Yes, I have confirmed. The speed of motion of the flakes increases when I blow on them.

Answer (score 9):

Those are flakes of lampblack. Their wettability in water is unequal around their periphery. This allows surface tension forces to apply a netforce in some random direction on the flake and force it to scoot around, until the wettability difference goes away as the water begins to wet out the previously poorly-wetting spots.

Comment: But if the flakes were independently subjected to random forces, they wouldn't move cohesively as they do in the animation. I believe, as I propose in my answer, that the flakes are being driven either by air currents around the drop of by convection in the drop.

Comment: sounds like an experiment needs to be performed!

Comment: Indeed. Now there's a new piece of evidence: the OP commented in my answer that blowing over the drop make the flakes move faster.

Comment: very cool! if there is no air movement, is there any residual particle movement at all? keep me posted- NN

Comment: @Gert - where does the energy come from to do this?